# Python `astimezone` nondeterministic behaviour

Tags: python, docker, datetime

Consider this lambda function to convert ISO date string to UTC:

```
import datetime

iso_to_utc = lambda iso: datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(iso).astimezone(
    datetime.timezone.utc
)
```

It works as expected in my local python 3.10 installation:

```
>>> iso_to_utc('2022-03-24T10:49:45')
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 24, 6, 49, 45, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

>>> iso_to_utc('2022-03-24T14:56:05-04:00')  # with UTC offset
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 24, 18, 56, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Out of the two examples above, the former one (without UTC offset) returns different result when running inside docker container:

```
>>> iso_to_utc('2022-03-24T10:49:45')
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 24, 10, 49, 45, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

What can be cause for this nondeterministic behaviour?

**Note:** My docker image is **python:3.10-alpine**

Comment: Well it *is* deterministic; it's just that Python using local time by default (if naive) may not be *intuitive*. Side note: named lambdas are discouraged, better use a `def` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is different system timezone in host machine and docker container. [Relevant python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) says:

> If self is naive, it is presumed to represent time in the system
> timezone.

Host machine's system timezone is correctly set to your local timezone, while in docker container it is *UTC*, by default. So, no adjustment is applied inside docker since target and system timezones point to the same *UTC* timezone.

Comment: if you *know* your input like `'2022-03-24T10:49:45'` represents UTC, I'd check `if dtobj.tzinfo is None:` and then replace it with `timezone.utc` if true - before conversion to another UTC offset.

Comment: I did it just now after discovering this default system timezone thing. In my case, it's not UTC, but other timezone is presumed if it's naive. So, I'm replacing `tzinfo` directly, before converting to UTC.